# socket.io-client + react, where to connect to the server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, reactjs

I'm writing a very simple Nodejs app. I use React + Socket.io.

There's a root element which immediately renders another react component (you may wonder why I have this root element. The reason is that I want to be able to mount one of the two components after receiving a message from server, but for the start I render a preselected component). 
In this root component , I define a socket in `componentDidMount` . Now the problem is that I want to pass this socket to all of the children (so they can listen and communicate with the server messages.) But if I connect to the server in `componentDidMount` of the root, during the rendering there is no socket as it's not connected yet and `null` will be passed to the child components.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
var UsersList = require('./usersList');
var Game = require('./game');
var socket;

var Snake = React.createClass({

    displayName: 'Snake',

    propTypes: {},

    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {};
    },

    mixins: [],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return ({
            usersList: true,
            game: false
        });
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.socket.close();
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        socket = ioClient.connect(); // this happens after render
    },
    render: function() {
        var result = null;
        if (this.state.usersList) {
            result = <UsersList socket={socket}/> // therefore this one is passed as null
        } else { //game : true
            result = <Game socket={socket}/>
        }
        return (<div>
            {result}
        </div>)
    }
});

module.exports = Snake;

'use strict';

var React = require('react');

    var UsersList = React.createClass({

        displayName: 'UsersList',

        propTypes: {},

        getDefaultProps: function() {
            return {};
        },

        mixins: [],

        getInitialState: function() {
            return ({
                usersList:[]
            });
        },
        componentWillReceiveProps: function(){
        },
        componentWillMount: function() {
        },

        componentWillUnmount: function() {
        },

        componentDidMount: function(){ 
            var socket = this.props.socket; // this one was passed into the component as null
            socket.on('usersList', function(data){ // so this one returns an error
                this.setState({
                    usersList: data.usersList
                });
            });
        },
        render: function() {
            var users = [];
            for (var i = 0 ; i < this.state.usersList.length ; i++){
                users.push(<span>{this.state.usersList[i]}</span>);
            }
            return(<div>{users}</div>);
        }
    });

    module.exports = UsersList;
```

So , now you may ask why I don't put `io.connect()` in `componentWillMount` or at the top of the file. Well , it doesn't work ! it returns this error : `Cannot find property "protocol" ...`. 
I cannot put it in `render` , `componentWillMount` , top of the file ...

Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Hi, where do you specify the path to connect to the server? I mean, `ioClient.connect()` does not specify any path. I'm facing troubles to connect to my server, in fact, the server receives the connection, but in the client the socket keeps _connecting_ inmediately after `io.connect('http://localhost:3000/api/chat/connect', { path:'/api/chat/connect', reconnect: true, forceNew: true, jsonp: false, transports: ['websocket'] })`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could continue to connect in `componentDidMount`. It will not be immediately available to the component's children, but then you could do something like this in the children:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if ( this.props.socket ) {
      // do your connection logic here
   }
}
```

This will ensure that the children immediately connect when the socket is first connected and available to them. Inside the `if` statement you could also verify that `this.props.socket` is not equal to `prevProps.socket` to prevent a redundant connection attempt.